# What are the advantages/disadvantages of octagonal barrels?

Tags: guns

Some modern firearms can come with either round or octagonal barrels, such as the 45-70 Marlin Guide vs the 45-70 Marlin Cowboy.

What would the advantages of one over the other be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A octagonal barrel has several **advantages**,

- They look really cool and historic. The historical reason they were made that way is,

  > Practically all are barrels are now turned to a round circumference or shape, concentric with the bore. Our old gunsmith makers of muzzle loading rifles almost invariably make their barrels octagonal, or eight sided in shape, **most likely because none of them had a modern lathe with which they could turn them truly round, and they found it easier to make the barrel uniform by forging or grinding it into an octagon.**

  [Small Arms Design and Ballistics; Volume I by  Colonel Townsend Whelen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JX7IOY)

  Quote sent by the [Buffalo Bill Cody Center of the West](https://centerofthewest.org/research/) after I emailed and asked if they knew why.

  > There really is no clear cut answer but the **general consensus is that before the popularity of lathes it was easier to file flats than make a round barrel for cost and time saving.**

  Email from [Henry Repeating Arms](https://www.henryusa.com/) in response to my question.
- The flat surface will help one keep the barrel straight and not slanted when aiming

  > An octagon barrel has but one advantage-- **it calls attention to any canting or sideways tilting of the barrel when in the act of aiming**,

  [Small Arms Design and Ballistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JX7IOY)
- They can be slightly heavier/thicker than a round barrel.

  > Don't know that there is an actual "advantage" of an octagon over a round barrel other than usually they are **slightly heavier/thicker than a round barrel.**  Octagons are usually installed on firearms to **obtain a classic look.**

  Email from [McGowen Precision Barrels](http://mcgowenbarrel.com/)

The **disadvantages** include,

- Unequal expansion when in use.

  > and it may have a disadvantage in that it **may not expand equally when it heats up from firing.**

  [Small Arms Design and Ballistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JX7IOY)
- Cost more (at least in 1945).

  > Many think that an octagon barrel present a **great deal of beauty**, and it is doubtful if the disadvantages  would be at all apparent in a heavy barrel, but the **cost of making such a barrel today is rather excessive.**

  [Small Arms Design and Ballistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JX7IOY)

Answer (score 0):

Since the early barrels were made by forging with a hammer and anvil, the initial formation would have a flat on the top and bottom. Then, the sides would be formed, with additional flats at 45 degrees from them, so an octagon Bbl. is a natural shape.
An octagon Bbl. can be held quite firmly in a vise; a round one will slip out.
A dovetail cut into an octagon Bbl. is at full depth for a much longer length than with a round barrel. So it'll grab the sight, ramrod holder, etc. much more firmly. Take a close look at a dovetail that's cut into a round Bbl., at the top of the Bbl., it's distorted away from the part with the male dovetail.
The bedding surface on an oct. Bbl. is flat, easier to form and has a much wider contact area, than the more narrow "effective bottom" of a round Bbl. (due to the rounded bottom curving away quickly). The slightest gap towards the side of a round Bbl. means there's no practical contact there.
The channel in the wood for a round Bbl. could flatten slightly as the wood dries; allowing the bbl. and stock to shift side to side.
The flats next to the bottom of an oct. Bbl. provides a large surface to cradle the Bbl. securely.
Those who say there is no reason for the octagon barrel, that it's just a style, should study physics and machine design. Instead of being dismissive towards the old ways, they need to understand what they're looking at before offering an opinion.
I worked as a machine repairman and a conventional machinist for more than thirty years.

Comment: Why do you abbreviate "barrel" to Bbl? That does mean barrel, but not a gun barrel, an oil barrel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Because of flats and peaks. It would would be a stiffer barrel. Back in the day the barrel needed to be longer hense needed to be stiffer so to vibrate less. No most gun maker could make round barrels in the mid 1800s look at all the civil war rifles. And it was cheaper then to make a round barrel.

Comment: The Pilger process was patented in 1885, first round steel with no seams.